# Global Hotkey Alt+S is killing me on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, hotkeys, snipping-tool

Somehow <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> started lunching Snipping Tool on Windows 7. I can't find a way to disable it.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Snip tool overrides Chrome (alt+s)](https://superuser.com/questions/228884/windows-snip-tool-overrides-chrome-alts)

Comment: Nope :( Already checked that

Comment: OK. I Solved the problem. Thanks to Spy++ I identified application which introduced this global hotkey and disabled it.

Comment: Detailed answer can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows